# How to find the commutator group of $G= \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & b\\0 & 1 & c\\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} , a,b,c \in K \right\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K$ be a field.

Let $G= \left\{  \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & a & b\\0 & 1 & c\\0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right) , a,b,c \in K \right\}$.

> Find the commutator group $[G,G]$ of $G$.

I already found that $ [G,G] \subset \left\{  \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & \alpha\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right) , \alpha \in K \right\} $, but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \alpha\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and find $g,h \in G$ such that $A=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$. You can try a matrix $h$ with $a=b=c=1$. I let you find the suitable coefficients for $g$ (some of them will depend on $\alpha$).